# Find Common value against different id c# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have one table which is looking like this

| ID | UserID | UserEncryptValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | abcd |
| 2 | 2 | 1234 |
| 3 | 3 | qwert |
| 4 | 1 | rstuv (Common value for user 1 and 2) |
| 5 | 2 | rstuv (Common value for user 1 and 2) |
| 6 | 2 | 78901 (Common value for user 2 and 3) |
| 7 | 3 | 78901 (Common value for user 2 and 3) |
| 8 | 1 | Hello123 (Common value for user 1,2 and 3) |
| 9 | 2 | Hello123 (Common value for user 1,2 and 3) |
| 10 | 3 | Hello123 (Common value for user 1,2 and 3) |

Now I want to find if user 1 and 2 or 1, 2 and 3 have common value or not with use of Linq.

Comment: and where specifically should we help you? What have you tried already? What do you even mean by "common values"? Please share the expected outcome.

Comment: Do you only want to check for common values between 1 and 2, or 1,2 and 3? What about common values between 1 and 3, or perhaps 2 and 3?

Comment: i have tried with getting records related to id i'm searching for 
just suppose i wanted to know 1,2 and 3 has combination or not then i'm first fetching all records with userid 1,2 and 3 

But now i have multiple records of those id as i have shown you in above table 
now i want to figure out do they have common value or not

Comment: LINQ to objects or EF? What *specific* results do you want? It matters. You can group by Value in both and check whether a group has more than `UserID`. The `GROUP BY` generated by EF though won't return the original items

Comment: You're not going to get an answer here unless you post your actual attempts at trying to solve this problem. StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service, it is intended for people to ask question about _their own_ work.

Comment: So i'm creating a method which will take this userid in input and try to find a common value between them, if this userid has common encrypted value then it has to return this value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're mapping that table to an actual object like 'UserData' like this:

```
public class UserData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserEncryptValue { get; set; }
}
```

You can get the common values like this (userData is a list of UserData and represents your data):

```
var searchId = 1;
var commonValues = userData.GroupBy(user => user.UserEncryptValue)
                           .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1 && grp.Any(usr => usr.UserId == searchId))
                           .SelectMany(u => u);
```

This groups on the UserEncryptValue and only selects groups that have more than 1 value (has a match) and at least 1 of the user ids is equal to the searchId.

Answer (score 1):

`Table.Where(n => Table.Any(o => !(o === n) && o.UserEncryptValue == n.UserEncryptValue)).Select(n => n.UserID)`

Will return a collection of user id's for members of collection `Table` where at least on other member of the table has the same value `UserEncryptValue` but is not the same object

Learn LINQ to understand how this works and what you can do to tweak it.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0). In this case you would group by `UserEncryptValue`.

You can then examine each group and check which users are in each group.